# Arch Linux install: wlan0 is up but not connecting to Wi-Fi

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, network-interface, ping

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on a Lenovo Harman/Kardon IdeaCentre, and I can't start a working internet connection.

```
$ ping archlinux.org
ping: archlinux.org: Name or service not known
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

This is after I have connected to my home Wi-Fi. I tried using an external network interface but that did not work, I also tried running

```
$ systemctl start dchpcd@wlan0
Job for dhcpcd@wlan0.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

I have watched a couple of videos and nothing seemed to help. I tried running `ip link set wlan0 up` but that didn't seem to do anything. I have rebooted several times and that also didn't help. This is what comes up for `wlan0` interface when I run `ip link`:

```
4: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:22:33:44:55:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: After `ip link set wlan0 up` can you try running `dhcpcd`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn’t seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iwctl as instructed by the [Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) on the Arch-Linux wiki? It's generally not recommended to use videos when installing Arch, as Arch's base is typically updated monthly and this can result in changes to the installation process.

[iwctl instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd#iwctl)

For a little more clarification why you need to review this, setting wlan0 to "up" only administratively enables the interface, it **does not** connect you to a network. While utilizing ethernet, dhcp will enable you to gain a routable address within a network, that you already **are automatically communicating on the physical layer bidirectionally with**. When you use Wi-Fi (802.11) you **are not communicating bidirectionally on the physical layer** with a Wireless Access Point. This is where iwctl, and similar utilities come into play, they allow you to communicate and connect to Wireless Access Points by utilizing 802.11. On your standard full distribution, this is all handled for you, removing the necessity to manually connect to a WAP.

Not Directly related to the question but if your curious on how Ethernet establishes physical layer connectivity [here would be a start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer)

[And similarly for Wi-Fi/802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my installation. The `iwctl` utility would show *connected* to my WiFi but `ip a` would not return any IP address. To fix this, I:

1. Re-use your arch USB boot drive and chroot into your system

```bsh
$ mount /dev/YOUR_ROOT_DIRECTORY /mnt
$ arch-chroot /mnt
$ pacman --sync openresolv dhcpcd
# You may get warning here citing you're CHROOTED. Ignore them.
$ resolvconf -u
$ exit
$ umount /mnt
$ reboot now

# Boot into your system - Not the live image
# Ensure your services are running
$ sudo systemctl start dhcpcd.service
$ sudo systemctl start iwd.service
# Connect to your WiFi using iwd
```

Post the last step, verify if your system receives an IP address using `ip a`.

I've only JUST started using arch - Please excuse if inaccurate.

Reference links:

1. [iwd Utility](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#iwctl) : Select DNS manager
2. [OpenResolv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Openresolv) : Usage
3. [DHCPCD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dhcpcd)